# Generate Scripts Wizard hangs without scripting all objects

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to generate the database scripts(tables,triggers,views,procedures) in sql server 2008, all of sudden the scriptting wizards hang up at the end state saying that scripting is completed but the close button never enable, if i stop this some of the tablels are missing, please advise

Comment: It looks like there may be a [couple](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958793) [of](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/420145/generate-script-progress-locks-not-all-objects-scripted) [issues](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/378085/generate-scripts-fails-with-out-of-memory-exception) with that feature, have you installed the latest servicepack? And have you tried generating the scripts in some other way (e.g. with [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) or a third-party tool)?

Comment: Run the profiler while scripting.  You should get an idea of where it is hanging at least.  There could be all kinds of reasons really.

Comment: I am using script wizard, it will hangs abruptly some times hence some times works perfectly, not sure where is the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Install earlier SSMS version.
For me bug was at 15.0.18358.0, changed to 15.0.18338.0 and the wizard started working.

Answer (score 2):

If the wizard says "0 Remaining", this means it has determined all the objects that it needs to script, and is writing them out to your destination.  If you are writing to a file, go to that file location in Windows Explorer, and keep refreshing the view. If the file keeps growing in size, this means everything is fine and the data is still being written.  Be patient, and eventually the process will finish and the Close button will become enabled.